# Why will Rails Console not load Changes to ruby file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

I am writing a script that I run in the rails console.

When I make a change to the file, even if I exit and reload the rails console, it does not recognize these changes.

How do I make rails recognize and load changes to this file?

The file is in the root of my application. I load the rails console and run:

```
require 'file.rb'
```

The file will run fine the first time, but if I make changes to the file they are not loaded. I could delete all the code in the file and run the file again and it still runs as it did before the edits.

Comment: Changes to what file? Is it in a subdirectory? How are you getting the console to run it? What directory are you currently running the console in? Could you please make your question more specific?!

Comment: Try to run `reload!` in your console after each changes

Comment: Agreed with @MrYoshiji, would you post as the answer?

Comment: I won't until @Davey confirms it's the actual solution to his problem ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're making changes to files that are stored within the `app/` directory, you can reload these with the `reload!` command.

If you're making changes outside of that, you need to exit and restart your console.

As a note, the `.rb` extension is almost always omitted in a `require` call. Another thing to keep in mind is that `require 'file'` will look in your `$LOAD_PATH` for something called `file.rb` and will load in the first one. It's possible you have two files with the same name. Try renaming it to see if that has any effect.

Rails has a pretty good auto-loader so it's usually not necessary to use `require` if you put your files in the correct place to start with. For example, `MyClass` could go in `app/models/my_class.rb` and would load automatically. The autoloader can be configured to look in different places as well.

Comment: An update/addition for those finding this in 2023 (hello from the future!) – `reload!` will also reload files targeted for autoloading in your `config/application.rb` file (e.g. files in your `lib/` folder), outside the `app/` directory.